# Binding DataGrid visibility with its own (ItemSource.Count > 0) Silverlight MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm, datagrid

As the title suggest I want to hide my grid when its itemsource has 0 rows.

```
<sdk:DataGrid Name="RegionDataGrid" Visibility="{Binding <!-- WHAT_SHOULD_COME_HERE -->}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsReadOnly="False" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a converter which will return Collapsed when List is empty.

```
public class EmptyCollectionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ICollection list = (ICollection)value;

        if (list == null)
            return Visibility.Collapsed;

        return list.Count != 0 ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you can use **RelativeSource** binding with value **Self** to bind the ItemsSource,

```
<sdk:DataGrid Visibility="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource EmptyCollectionConverter}}" />
```